# Unterschied zwischen »komplementär« und »ergänzend«

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Daher wollen wir im Folgenden den Blick auf eine [...] ungewöhnliche Innovation im Wirtschafts- und Finanzsystem richten. Sie hat das Potenzial [...] die Welt zum Positiven zu verändern: ***Komplementäre***, **ergänzende** Währungssysteme, die neben der staatlichen, »offiziellen« Währung in der Regel mit der Zielsetzung eingeführt werden, [...] die Lebenssituation aller Beteiligten zu verbessern.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen »komplementär« und »ergänzend« (in diesem Zusammenhang)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So habe ich es gelernt:

> Zwei Sachen sind *komplementär*, wenn sie in irgendeinem Aspekt *gegensätzlich* sind und zusammen etwas *vervollständigen*. Also etwas mehr als nur *ergänzend* (anfüllend). Ergänzendes muss nicht unbedingt vervolständigen oder gegensätzlich sein.